# Mounting and Enabling Write Access to Windows Drive

Tags: 11.10, ntfs, automount

I wanted to auto-mount all the partitions in my system, (*i.e.* the C,D,E and F drives from windows). I used ntfs config tool to do that, but it throws me an error when I check the mount selection for my C drive, the one that has Windows installed on it. Now, I´ve lost complete access to my Windows Partition, I cannot open it in Nautilus either, though I could do that before I used ntfs config tool.

Its throwing me this error

> Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
>   mount: according to mtab, /dev/sda1 is mounted on /media/Windows\040
>   mount failed

What should I do??
Please help!!!

Comment: Are you using wubi ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unmounting the mounted drive?

```
umount /dev/sda1
```

After that you should be able to mount the drive using Nautilus.  You might want to consider mounting your samba shares by editing your /etc/fstab.  It should look something like this:

```
//192.168.0.0/directory /mnt/mountpoint smbfs user,credentials=/etc/samba/cred-file 0 0 0
```

Good luck!